# Dreamweaver: Auto-Indent JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

I am using a template website that I downloaded online. Everything works - problem is all of the JavaScript in my project is unreadable as it is all written as **one** line. My thought is that downloading it caused all of the spaces and indents in the .js document to go away and everything is left `lookinglikethisfortheentirepage`. That makes this very unreadable. Does anyone know of a way to auto-indent JS in Dreamweaver?

Comment: Probably file encoding UTF-8 vs ISO-8859-1 or other.  Match the encoding. Could be `\r` `\n` handling, too.

Comment: You sure you aren't looking at a minified version of the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

paste the code in [**the javascript beautifier**](http://jsbeautifier.org/), click beautify and then paste that into dreamweaver.

Hope that helps, happy new year!

Comment: Works like a charm. Happy new year to you my friend!

Comment: Thanks! By the way you probably were looking at the minified version of the code, websites upload their code without blank spaces to improve perfomance and loading times :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

```
Commands > Apply Source Formatting
Commands > Clean up HTML
```

Also, as a third option, try going to www.jsfiddle.net . You can paste you code there and click tidyup.

They work like magic

You can also use the Dreamweaver extension for JavaScript. Find it [here](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&loc=en_us&extid=2107536)